# Ember.js json routing not working

Tags: json, ember.js

Try to build an ember.js based web app but it doesn't work, http://wilhelminaschool.eu/app2/

with the app js i make a route and defining an url to a json file but the template doen'st show anything, what i'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to piggyback on splattne's answer,

this is incorrect in your `posts` handlebar template

```
{{#each posts}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{/posts}}
```

and should be

```
{{#each posts}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

you are opening and closing an each loop, and the handlebar tags need to be the same.

Comment: Thanx this helped me out:D i now see something, only thing now is that i want to trim a string and don't display html, suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to trim the string in the controlller or model, depending on what your scope is.  Additionally you can create a handlebars helper for trimming if you want.  I'm not sure what you mean by not display HTML, maybe you can create an example or submit another question explaining the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misspelled some URLs in your route's model functions:

```
http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/?json=get_page&page_id=10063');
```

Did you forget the /api segment?

and

```
http;//www.wilhelminaschool.eu/api/get_recent_posts');
```

the http://

Comment: then i get "each doesn't match posts" on http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/app2/#posts

Comment: this was indeed a problem

Answer (score 1):

You have cross origin issue getting the json from the server.
You need to add a header allow cross origin access to the server.

app/adapters/application.js

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/',
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With"
  }
});
```